# date index on R hourly data

Tags: r

I have a data frame with hourly data and I am trying to plot but I want date on x axis not just index as numbers, I want the dates to be shown on x axis

```
df = read.csv('~/Desktop/data.csv', header = TRUE , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$Date,format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
plot(df$column1)
```

[image: index date]

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example using for example `dput(yourDataframe[1:5,])`?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with, including a sample of data

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code seems to be that you feed a single variable into the `plot` command whereas what you want is a plot of `column1` **grouped by** dates, right? If that's the case then you could use this:

**DATA**:

```
set-seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  dates = rep(c("2009-01-01", "2009-01-02", "2009-01-03", "2009-01-04", "2009-01-05", "2009-01-06", "2009-01-07"), 1000),
  column1 = rnorm(7000, 100)
)
```

**SOLUTION**:

Then you could use `ggplot2`and `geom_jitter`to plot `column1` against `dates`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dates, y=column1)) + geom_jitter()
```

**RESULT**:

The resulting plot would roughly look like this:
[image]